# Problems with div tag & type any in styles-components (Gatsby app)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

i'm not sure what to do with this error. the thing still compiled successfully but my 
content inside the div still wont show up in the browser:

> ([ts] Property 'div' does not 
>   exist on type '(tag: any) => { (...args: any[]): any; withConfig(config: any): ...; 
>   attrs(attrs: any): ...; }'. [2339])

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 let iconNames = []
for (let index = 0; index < icons.length; index++) {
    iconNames.push(icons[index]["name"])
}
//align-items, for verticle
//justify-items, for horizontal
const Container = styled.div ` // <== error        is on this line here 
     height: 100%;
     display: grid;
     align-items: center; 
     justify-items: center; 
    `
// Define type of property
interface Props {
    name: string;
}
interface State {
    svg: any;
}
```

Comment: which version of styled-components & @types/styled-components are you using? also, is the space between `styled.div` and the backtick a typo here?

Comment: I didn’t think about the space. I will look into that as soon as I get my Mac out the car. I’m using the latest styled-components and the latest @styles as well and I’m using the stable node.js 11.*.*

Answer (score 4):

This problem went away for me by installing `@types/styled-components`